# In C++, how to get the path to a service in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, service, path, daemon

Given the name of a `service` or `daemon`, is there some way by which I can get the location of that service from a `C++` program in `Linux`?
I hope, one way is to search the `proc filesystem` using it `pid`. Does there exist some `Linux` functions for this?

Thank You

edit: To be more specific I am working on Linux equivalent code for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800532/getting-service-path-to-executable) program in Windows.

Comment: I tried the path of a program in execution. But was of no use

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: The same code as in the link

Comment: OK. From your post and comments it's not clear what means "was of no use", what was the error?

Comment: `*** Crashed with return code: 0 ***`

Comment: Which Link ? From Zelda ?

Comment: @icbytes : Sorry I modified the question. The link was [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525668/how-to-implement-readlink-to-find-the-path]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the system function and redirect its output to a file. Later on read that file. For example,

```
system ("which rsyslogd >service.out");
```

Then in the program, you can read service.out.

Comment: What if my service is not in a standard location as bin or sbin, etc

Comment: It should be in one of the directories in the PATH. Any particular reason for keeping it outside the directories in PATH?

Comment: May be in some cases will have to do so.

Comment: Well, in that case, instead of "which" you can use the "find" command in the system function and then use the output of "find" in the program.