# Get the service executable folder with POCO

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I need to find a way to retrieve the folder in which my executable is.
Since it is a service, the

```
Poco::Path::current()
```

returns the current working directory which is the system directory for Windows and the root directory in Linux.

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I think is quite clear: "I need to find a way to retrieve the folder in which my executable is"

Comment: then Poco::Path::current() should work correctly. Or you can look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800532/getting-service-path-to-executable).

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit of a pain to pass around your program, but argv[0] in your main() should hold the executable's path.